# Storing version of dependency in variable in gradle

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How should I store dependency version  in variable in gradle build script without error from Android Studio?

When I make this:

```
def guavaVersion = '17.0'
compile "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
```

I have:
`A newer version of com.google.guava:guava than $guavaVersion is available: 17`

Comment: Isn't that an informational message rather than an error? Are you perhaps using single quotes instead of double quotes for the dependency string (second line)? Otherwise it's probably time to raise an issue for Android Studio.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

try this:

```
ext.guavaVersion = '17.0'
compile "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
```

Comment: Do you get this again? A newer version of com.google.guava:guava than $guavaVersion is available: 17? It should not happen. Are you using double quotes in this: compile "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"

Comment: Note: `ext.guavaVersion ` should be declared inside `dependencies {...}` block

Comment: What worked for me is a combination of `project.ext.guavaVersion = '17.0'` and `compile "com.google.guava:guava:"+program.guavaVersion`