# Android Studio Gradle Dependency Check

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to develop a Google Play Services like structure which is split into its own separate components (libraries) that can be added to Android Studio as dependencies. For example what is displayed below;

[image]

Like the Play Services libraries I would like to force the user to use the same version for all the libraries when adding more than one, as seen below;

[image]

I am wondering how the build.gradle file determines this? Is it built into Android Studio, is it coming from the build tools plugin?

As I would like to do something like this, if anyone has any helpful suggestions/links it would much appreciated.

Comment: Like suggested before these are lint checks. You could define them yourself. Furthermore i would suggest extracting the version number into a variable and having it common across each of them.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520487/storing-version-of-dependency-in-variable-in-gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Lint to define custom rules based on your needs.
There is a really good explanation on topic with an example on *Android Studio Project Site*.

An easy way to start defining your own Lint rules is by modifying the sample project provided at this link http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules/customlint.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

This way you will have all the dependencies set up to use the Lint APIs.

Source http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules

Comment: aha Lint way more simple than what I was thinking.